# How to continuously add objects to nested collection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a React/Redux app that uses Firebase Auth/Firestore to keep track of a user's gym exercises. I have Redux Form to handle data submission and I have the below example data structure I want to achieve in Firestore:

```
users {
  id {
    name: 'John Smith'
    uid: 'k1s7fxo9oe2ls9u' (comes from Firebase Auth)
    exercises: {
      {
        name: 'Bench Press',
        sets: 3,
        reps: 10,
        lbs: 100,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to keep adding new exercise objects to the exercises subcollection (in Firestore I guess it would be a field type of map). What I want to do is have new objects in "exercises" as the user submits new forms. So for example, if the user wanted to add a Deadlift exercise, it would look like the below:

```
   users {
      id {
        name: 'John Smith'
        uid: 'k1s7fxo9oe2ls9u' (comes from Firebase Auth)
        exercises: {
          {
            name: 'Bench Press',
            sets: 3,
            reps: 10,
            lbs: 100,
          },
          {
            name: 'Deadlift',
            sets: 3,
            reps: 12,
            lbs: 120,
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Calling `db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).add({"exercises": values});`
 just updates the Bench Press object that's there already rather than adding a new one on submission of the form.

But calling `db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).add({"exercises": values});` gives me this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function.

I've been struggling with this for quite a while, any help is hugely appreciated.

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import db from '../../../firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import { store } from '../../../App';

const formSubmit = (values)=> {
    const currentUserId = store.getState().auth.uid;

    db.collection("users").get().then((usersSnapshot) => {
        usersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // looking for the current user and then updating their data
          if(doc.data().uid === currentUserId) {
            db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).add({
              "exercises": values,
            });
          }
        });
      });
}


let ExercisesForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <Field name="name" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Exercise Name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Field name="sets" component="input" type="number" />
        <label htmlFor="sets"> sets</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Field name="reps" component="input" type="number" />
        <label htmlFor="reps"> reps</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Field name="lbs" component="input" type="number" />
        <label htmlFor="lbs"> lbs</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
)

ExercisesForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'exercise'
})(ExercisesForm)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  uid: state.auth.uid,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  undefined
)(ExercisesForm);
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Is exercises really a subcollection, or just an array field on the user doc?  Those are different things.  Please be clear about how you're organizing your data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's meant to be a subcollection. As the user completes the form, a new object is to be added to it, so for example if the user wanted to add a deadlift exercise, the data then looks like this:

users {
  id {
    name: 'John Smith'
    uid: 'k1s7fxo9oe2ls9u' (comes from Firebase Auth)
    exercises: {
      {
        name: 'Bench Press',
        sets: 3,
        reps: 10,
        lbs: 100,
      },
      {
        name: 'Deadlift',
        sets: 3,
        reps: 10,
        lbs: 150,
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I've edited the question so that the example I gave could be formatted. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to say:

```
db
    .collection('users')
    .doc(doc.id)
    .collection('exercises')
    .add(values);
```

Where `values` contains all the fields of the document you want to add.  It will create a new document with a random id in the exercises subcollection.

Comment: Wow this works, I swear I tried that before and it gave me an error. I must have missed a small bit of syntax somewhere (it was 4AM haha) or maybe my existing dummy data didn't play nice with it since I just tried this with a clean slate. Thanks for coming back to this!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there is no way to iterate over the subcollection 'exercises', should you need to retrieve them or find a certain entry.

Answer (score 1):

So this won't work in the latest version of **Firebase V9**.

So below is how I added a subcollection to a document in the latest version:

```
const docRef = doc(database, "userDocs", session.user.email);
const colRef = collection(docRef, "docs");

await addDoc(colRef, {
  fileName: input,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log("CREATED");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error creating document", err);
  });
```

This will created a structure like

```
userDocs 
   -> userEmail 
        -> docs 
           -> uid 
             -> data
```